# I can't pass variables if I put my admin in a different folder in codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter

I did: controller - admin - files
        and  views - admin - files

In the files outside admin everything runs ok (the form with the login works fine), but when I do my admin and do the new form in order to do a new login, the form don't pass the variables.

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
    <?php

    class Validausuarioadmin extends CI_Controller {

    function login()
       {

  if(!isset($_POST['maillogin2'])){   
   $this->load->view('admin/header'); 
     $this->load->view('admin/contenido');      
 $this->load->view('admin/footer'); 
      }
      else{                        
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('maillogin2','e-mail','required|valid_email');      
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('passwordlogin2','password','required');

    if(($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)){           
       $this->load->view('admin/header'); 
   $this->load->view('admin/contenido');                   
        $this->load->view('admin/footer');
     }
     else{                                       
        $this->load->model('ingresoadmin_model');
        $ExisteUsuarioyPassoword=$this->ingresoadmin_model     >ValidarUsuario($_POST['maillogin2'],$_POST['passwordlogin2']);   
        if($ExisteUsuarioyPassoword){   .
           echo "Validation Ok<br><br><a href=''>Back</a>";   
        }
        else{  
           $data['error']="wrong E-mail or password";
           $this->load->view('admin/contenido',$data);   
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   ?>
```

View:

```
<?php  echo form_open('admin/validausuarioadmin/login'); ?> 

  User:


<input type="text" name="maillogin2" value="<?= set_value('maillogin2'); ?>" size="20" />


 Password:

 <input type="password" name="passwordlogin2" value="<?= set_value('passwordlogin2'); ?>" size="20" />


 <input type="submit" value="Enter">


        <?
             if(isset($error)){
             echo "<p>".$error."</p>";
            }
            echo form_error('maillogin2');
        ?>

        <?= form_error('passwordlogin2');?>

         <?=form_close();?>
```

If I change form_open('admin/validausuarioadmin/login') to form_open('validausuarioadmin/login') the variables pass perfectly, but the view got damaged.

I would appreciate a lot your help. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: What is your folder structure of views. Explain clearly.

Comment: I have a public page with all the files in views, and works perfectly. I create a folder "admin" in views and one in controllers, because I need to be organized, that's all